# how to override a style on a particular child

Tags: css

```
<div class="post-inner-content">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p> Some text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post-inner-content">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p> <img src="blahblah" class="img_content"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example post-inner-content has a left and right padding of 10vw. I want it to be 0 when the paragraph contains an image. The structure of the HTML & CSS is largely foisted upon me by my Wordpress theme so I can't restructure it.

I've tried this and every permutation of it I can think of but it doesn't override the setting - there's no change.

```
div.post-inner-content>div.entry-content>p>img.img_content {padding: 0;}
```

I've tried with and without spaces around the >, and also with no >. I've tried being more specific and less specific. I suspect it doesn't work because I am setting the padding on the child, not the parent.

I've also tried setting the padding to 0 everywhere (which works) and using :not to apply it everywhere but the image as follows (which doesn't):

```
div.post-inner-content{padding: 0;}
div.entry-content p :not(.img_content) {padding:0 10vw; }
```

Comment: The way you have it now, it's not possible to be done with just CSS, you will need javascript. If you can change the html though, you can add a class to the parent to indicate that it contains an image, and go from there. Multiple classes are separated with a space in the HTML and selected with concatenating them as so `div.class1.class2` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be better off moving that class to one of the parent divs which will give you more flexibility when selecting elements:

```
<div class="post-inner-content">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p> Some text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post-inner-content img_content">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p> <img src="blahblah"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your CSS would be something like:

```
div.post-inner-content p {}
div.post-inner-content.img_content p {} // will override the above
```

You could also add the class to entry-content if you wanted, or the p itself, but the higher up the parent the more control you'll have over the conditional styling of the children, just be smart about it.

Comment: I found that changing the html via php was much easier than anything else. Should have considered that from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a negative margin of 10px on the image to "undo" the padding, or rather to cause the image to display over the padding.

```css
 .post-inner-content {
   padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   background-color: #ddd;
 }

img {
  margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-inner-content">
  <div><p>Hello Bob.</p></div>
</div>

<div class="post-inner-content">
  <div><p><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8oli.jpg"></p></div>
</div>
```